# Print a Tree of Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, tree

I am writing minimax as part of a project, but its awfully hard to check that it is working correctly. If I could print a tree of what it does, it would be extremely useful.

Is there an easy way to print a tree of recursive calls, selecting whatever variables are important to the situation?

Comment: How about using a Visitor to traverse the tree and print each visited treenode? Or using an appropriate toString() method on each node?

Comment: @Dirk: in the minimax algorithm, you don't actually build a tree in memory. The tree structure is implicit in the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of recursion depth by means of a parameter (in minimax, you'd do that anyway). Then print depth * a small number of spaces, followed by the interesting variables in each call to obtain

```
player=1, move=...
  player=2, move=...
    player=1, move=...
    ...
  player=2, move=...
```

You might also want to print the return value of each recursive call.

If you desperately want a pretty picture of a tree, post-process the output of the above and feed it to a tree-drawing package.